# what would cause EF Code First IDatabaseInitializer InitializeDatabase to not get called?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a custom initializer setup as follows:

```
public class PromptIfChangesNeededDBInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<MeyerREContext>
{

    public PromptIfChangesNeededDBInitializer()
    {  // This constructor is called properly

    }

    #region IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> Members


    public void InitializeDatabase(MeyerREContext context)
    { // This is never called

       ... Code that checks existence and seeds etc

    }

 }
```

Here is my DbContext class

```
public class MeyerREContext : DbContext
{
    static MeyerREContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new PromptIfChangesNeededDBInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    ... More DbSet property definitions


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

       modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressMap());
      ... More Configurations 

    }

}
```

This is the first call to the context

```
City city = dbNew.Cities.Where(e=>e.CityName=="Foley").FirstOrDefault();
```

The constructor of the Initializer is called properly as confirmed by a breakpoint, the OnModelCreating runs properly as confirmed by a breakpoint, but after the OnModelCreating is completed the InitializeDatabase is never called...

I removed the Database.SetInitializer(new PromptIfChangesNeededDBInitializer()) call from the ctor of the DBContext into the ctor of the calling class BEFORE any calls to the context and I get slightly different behavior now:

```
public class CreateData
{

    private VFPModelContainer db = new VFPModelContainer();
    private MeyerREContext dbNew;

    public CreateData()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new PromptIfChangesNeededDBInitializer<MeyerREContext>());

        dbNew = new MeyerREContext();
        dbNew.Database.Initialize(force: true);   NUll Exception here now...

    }
```

A null exception is geenrated now in the EF Framework code:

Here is the exception detail:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=EntityFramework
StackTrace:
   at    
    System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.ValidateConsistency(NavigationPropertyConfiguration navigationPropertyConfiguration)
```

InnerException:

It looks like the exception is happening in one of the EntityTypeConfiguration calls, but the exception is being swallowed somehow ?  How can I figure out which call it is ?  There are around 100 entities in this model...

[image: How can I get more info than is shown in the Intellitrace ?]

How to get more info about what went wrong inside EF ?  I need to know which navigational property is having problems... I think the problem is that EF is creating background worker threads to create & validate the model, but I don't understand why the exception is soooo vague ??

Any ideas ?

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Initializer is not called until you make real access to the database (execute query or save changes).

Comment: Sorry, I left that part out, I will edit it, it is attempting to create the model etc on the first call to the context...

Comment: Your first code (with the static constructor) should actually work. Are you sure that you don't get an exception and the exception is catched and ignored somehow in your code? `InitializeDatabase` is called *after* `OnModelCreating`. Did you check if you reach the end of `OnModelCreating` with a breakpoint? If not, step over the 100 lines where you add the configurations to see where it breaks.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that it makes it through all of the configurations without an exception... The exception occurs between the last line of OnModelCreating and right before the InitializeDatabase call... So its somewhere in the EF code in a method named NavigationPropertyConfiguration.ValidateConsistency(NavigationPropertyConfiguration navigationPropertyConfiguration) It is a null reference exception...  How can I get more exception detail about which navigation property is causing the problem from that exception ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

had to install Reflector and Decompile the EF Assembly to find out what the problem was:

This is the line that causes the problem...

```
private void ValidateConsistency(NavigationPropertyConfiguration navigationPropertyConfiguration)
{
  if ((navigationPropertyConfiguration.InverseEndKind.HasValue && this.EndKind.HasValue) && (navigationPropertyConfiguration.InverseEndKind != this.EndKind))
  {
    throw System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Resources.Error.ConflictingMultiplicities(this.NavigationProperty.Name, this.NavigationProperty.ReflectedType);
  }
  if ((navigationPropertyConfiguration.EndKind.HasValue && this.InverseEndKind.HasValue) && (navigationPropertyConfiguration.EndKind != this.InverseEndKind))
  {
    throw System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Resources.Error.ConflictingMultiplicities(this.InverseNavigationProperty.Name, this.InverseNavigationProperty.ReflectedType);
  }
```

In my case the InverseNavigationProperty property is null which causes and exception WHEN EF is trying to throw an exception...

The underlying problem is that I had an inverse property relationship defined but no mapping defined for it...

However, it was impossible to acertain which entity was causing this problem... These checks in this method should be wrapped with a try catch to avoid this problem so they can throw a more meaningful error to the end user...

Thanks
Greg